# Merge ttwo tables using order id number where one table has multiple rows with the same id number

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice, spreadsheet

I'll first explain what I'm trying to accomplish then give the table details.  I'm trying to export sales data from my website and organize it by order id number so I can easily see which orders were placed by wholesale customers and which weren't as well as which orders failed.  The end goal is to be able to get a total quantity of an item sold and also see if it was wholesale or not.

The problem is that my site will only export the data in two separate tables.

Table 1 has the ORDER ID NUMBER and all the customer information including membership level and if an order is processed, complete, failed, etc.

Table 2 has the order information. 
If more than one product was ordered, it will list the items in different rows
and each row has the (same) ORDER ID NUMBER in Column `A`.

Here is an example of the tables with the irrelevant columns removed...

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

Here is what I want the output to look like...

[image: Output Result]

Comment: (1) This looks / sounds like a typical case for using `VLOOKUP`.  What have you tried? (2) We prefer that example data be posted as text rather than images.

Comment: sorry for the image, it is my first time on here and when I tried pasting my samples it told me it had to change them from the spreadsheet to an image.  I'll do it right next time.  I've tried VLOOKUP, found some sample code on line =VLOOKUP(A1;Sheet2.$A$1:$B$3;2;0) I made 2 junk tables with numbers and letters just to see if I could get it to work but didn't have any luck.  It sort of worked but only if the A1 numbers were in the exact same order in both tables.  If I changed the order of the A1 numbers then it put the incorrect letters into the adjacent cell.  I also tried CONSOLIDATE data.